# HTML time input validation using regex ( don't allow 00:00 but want allow 24:00)

Tags: html, regex, angular, validation

For input type as time in **hh:mm** format validation,
tried below pattern

```
pattern="^([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$"
```

Requirement is need to restrict *00:00* and allow *24:00*,
so updated pattern as

```
pattern="^(24:00)|(([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d))$"
```

Now it is allowing 24:00, Please help how to restrict 00:00 format,

Link (Sample Code): 
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPCIVB1OCQ04

Comment: (?!00:00)(([01]\d|2[0-4]):([0-5]\d)) https://regex101.com/r/254gIw/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex should works:

```
^(?!00:00)(24:00|([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d)$
```

**Explanation**:

[image]

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YJN3Wq/3) - updated^2

You can read more about regex `negative lookahead` in this [link](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Thanks @SaeedFalsafin i took (?!00:00)

Comment: You dont want to get "24:05"?

Comment: Now, This is the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
^(24:00)|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d))|(00:(0[1-9]|[1-5][0-9]))$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xSqRUr/4/)

It has extra handling for `00` hour allowing only non-zero minute part.

Comment: Fixed for `00:11` and updated the demo link. Thanks @PeterB

Comment: I think you and me answered the same :(

Comment: this pattern allows 00:77. Please check as it's not correct.

Comment: Couldn't `00:(0[1-9]|[1-5]0|[1-5][1-9])` be shorten to `00:(0[1-9]|[1-5][0-9])`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this `^(24:00)|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d))|(00:(0[1-5]|[1-9]0|[1-5][1-9]))$`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Takes 00:01 to 24:00, we need to restrict 00:00</p>

<form action="#">
  Input: <input type="text" name="time_input" pattern="^(24:00)|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d))|(00:(0[1-5]|[1-9]0|[1-5][1-9]))$" title="Invalid input">

  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't match `00:07` but matches `00:90`. This doesn't need to be this long really.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please `"^(20|21|22|23|[01]d|d)(([:][0-5]d){1,2})$"`

edited as suggested

```
"^(24:00)|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d))|(00:(0[1-9]|[1-5]\d))$"
```

this should work fine

Comment: Could be a comment.

Comment: reputation is less than 50. Can't comment everywhere

Comment: also same for you as well. :)

Comment: You should use `\d` instead of `d`. Even with that changed, it still does not allow `24:00`

Comment: @Ramesh : your pattern allows 00:77. Please check as it's not correct

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need `^` and `$` anchors on `pattern` attribute. They are automatically applied [against input string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes):

> A regular expression that the control's value is checked against. The
>   `pattern` must match the entire value, not just some subset.

Secondly, you only need to prepend to your regex a negative lookahead to do an immediate failure on `00:00`:

```
pattern="(?!00:00)(?:(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d|24:00)"
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this may be help full to you

```
 (?!00)[0-2][0-4]:[0-5][0-9]
```

Comment: This does not allow anything that starts with `00:`

Comment: You need to test before you post, it still does not match `00:`